# Magento 2: create custom module date picker in admin configuration

Tags: magento-2.0.7

How to create custom module date picker in magento 2 system.xml ?

Comment: see this link http://www.magewallet.com/blog/magento-2/magento-2-add-calendar-admin-configuration-options/

Comment: Do you want datetime ??

Comment: Yes.. i need datetime option in admin configuration

Comment: Thans for your response, i will check and let you know.

Comment: It is working for me.. Thank you Bhupendra